# Haskell : How do I compose a recursive function that takes an element and gives gives back its list, but having different data type?

Tags: haskell, types, recursion

Say I have a data types as follows:

```
 data Cell = Cell (Maybe Player)
 data Board = Board [[Cell]]
```

Now I want to generate a recursive function like this:

```
 genBoard :: [Cell] -> Board
 genBoard [] = []
 genBoard c = (take 3 c) : (genBoard $ drop 3 c) -- takes list of 9 Cells and gives 3x3 list of cells
```

Obviously the above code fails as (:) can't prepend [Cell] to Board although technically, Board is nothing more than [[Cell]]. I need to have the Board as a separate data type to provide my own show function for it.

The best I have come up with so far is this:

```
genBoardList :: [Cell] -> [[Cell]]
genBoardList [] = []
genBoardList c =  (take 3 c) : (genBoardList $ drop 3 c)

boardListToBoard :: [[Cell]] -> Board
boardListToBoard [] = Board []
boardListToBoard s = Board s

genBoard :: [Cell] -> Board
genBoard = boardListToBoard . genBoardList
```

But this seems a bit too long and hackish to accomplish a seemingly simple thing. Any ideas how I can improve my code?

Comment: By the way, your `boardListToBoard` function could be replaced with `Board` (i.e. `genBoard = Board . genBoardList`). Also note that there's no need to treat the `[]` case separately.

Answer (score 5):

You just have to unwrap the list from the `Board` constructor using pattern matching, and then wrap it back up on each step; for example, using `let...in`:

```
genBoard :: [Cell] -> Board
genBoard [] = []
genBoard cs =
    let Board css = genBoard (drop 3 cs)
    in Board (take 3 cs : css)
```

Or, more idiomatically, a `where` clause:

```
genBoard :: [Cell] -> Board
genBoard [] = []
genBoard cs = Board (take 3 cs : css)
  where
    Board css = genBoard (drop 3 cs)
```

Another improvement would be to use pattern-matching instead of `take` and `drop`:

```
genBoard :: [Cell] -> Board
genBoard [] = []
genBoard (c0:c1:c2:cs) = Board $ [c0, c1, c2] : css
  where
    Board css = genBoard cs
```

You could also make it simpler using the [split](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split) package:

```
genBoard :: [Cell] -> Board
genBoard = Board . splitEvery 3
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a lifting function that turns functions on `[[Cell]]` into functions on `Board`:

```
liftBoard :: ([[Cell]] -> [[Cell]]) -> Board -> Board
liftBoard f (Board css) = Board (f css)
```

With this you can turn the `(take 3 c) :` into something that can be used on the `Board` returned by the recursive `genBoard` call:

```
genBoard :: [Cell] -> Board
genBoard [] = Board []
genBoard c  = liftBoard (take 3 c :) $ genBoard (drop 3 c)
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that for types that are just wrappers around other types, it's better to use newtype (no runtime overhead, newtypes are just a compile-time facility) :

```
newtype Board = Board [[Cell]]
```

You can use record syntax to make the "deconstructor" for you too :

```
newtype Board = Board { boardContent :: [[Cell]] }
```

Then you can "lift" a function on [[Cell]] to a function on Board simply :

```
liftBoard f = Board . f . boardContent

genBoard cs  = liftBoard (take 3 cs :) (genBoard (drop 3 cs))
```

But all that may not be necessary at all, if you just use a type synonym. Do you really need a datatype for your board or did you just give it a name for convenience and documentation ? The advantage of using newtype or data is that you won't be able to mix [[Cell]] and Board but do you really use [[Cell]] for anything else than your boards ? You would also be unable to define new instance on Board if you use a type synonym, does that bother you ?

If the answer to both question is no, just use :

```
type Board = [[Cell]]

genBoard :: [Cell] -> Board
genBoard [] = []
genBoard cs =  take 3 cs : genBoard (drop 3 cs)
```